# Copy photos off iPhone without iPhoto?

Tags: iphone, photos

I have a Mac that doesn't have iPhoto installed on it, which I use for syncing with my iPhone. Is there any way I can copy images from my phone to my Mac (other than email) without purchasing a copy of iPhoto?

Comment: I have iPhoto on my mac and never purchased it. I always thought it comes along with OS X for free.

Comment: @Cawas it comes with every mac (ie. pre-installed), but not on the install DVDs

Comment: @loic well, I rather use **picasa** anyway! ;-P

Comment: @loic @Cawas there usually is now two DVD's that come with every Mac, the OS install and the Applications install.

Comment: @jml yes, with every Mac. But when I bought (snow) leopard, it wasn't on them

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Use Image Capture.** You'll find it in your Applications folder. It's surprisingly robust, and it's made by Apple.

Comment: Will this extract video as well? **edit, it will http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083

Comment: great, iPhoto is changing photo size and etc. so this i great solution

Answer (score 12):

You can also use **Preview**, go File -> Import from iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try apps like [DropPhox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropphox/id411118930?mt=8) which will sync your pictures to Dropbox as soon as you click them. Very handy!